# Multiple jQuery problems for 'Wack-A-Mole' style game

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, 2d-games

I'm really trying hard to work through this but keep running into problems.
Its a game where mice pop up and you hit them and gain points. Hopefully you can see it here...
http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/wackamouse/index.html

What I want to happen eventually is for the mice to pop up after a random delay then go down again. Once they are up they become 'clickable' This is the class that gets added when they're up.

Click events however don't work for classes that have been added dynamically. I found a question which should have answered that problem but it made no sense to me.

Also the delay seems to get shorter and shorter. Is that my computer caching it and speeding up? Is there any way of making the delay timing consistent. Or at least near real seconds.

Here is the jQuery code so far...

```
var score = 0;  

$(document).ready(function() {


function mouseShow(){

    $('.mouse').each(function() {
        var $mouse = $(this);
        var min = 7000, max = 13000;
        var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        setTimeout(function(){

            $mouse.animate({
                'background-position-x': '0',
                'background-position-y': '0'
            }, 300, function() {
                $mouse.addClass('clickable');
                mouseHide();
            });

        },  delay);

    });

}

function mouseHide(){

    $('.mouse').each(function() {
        var $mouse = $(this);
        var min = 4000, max = 6000;
        var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $mouse.removeClass('clickable');
            $mouse.animate({
                'background-position-x': '0',
                'background-position-y': '40px'
            }, 300, function() {
                mouseShow();
            });

        },  delay);

    });

}

mouseShow();

    $('.clickable').click(function() {


        $('.score p').remove();
        score += 1;
        $('.score').append( "<p>"+score+"</p>" );
        console.log(score);

    });




});
```

Comment: +1 for cute demo :) Ignore the above comment from `edgeofmystery` as they show a *non*-delegated event handler as their example (which will just confuse you)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a *delegated event handler* attached to a *non-changing ancestor element* of your mice (e.g the `.mice` div) e.g.:

```
$('.mice').on('click', '.clickable', function() {
```

It works by listening for events bubbling up to the target element, *then* applying the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble-chain, *then* applying the function *to any elements that caused the event*. The end result is the `.clickable` elements only need to match at event time. This requires only one handler for many items and the overhead is quite low (and as you can only click a few times per second the performance difference is negligible)

Re: the delay, it is difficult to see with random numbers. Try it with a fixed duration to test performance, then switch to random.